# Given two solution vectors - finding the general solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Could anyone try and help me out with this question?

Given $A$, a $3X3$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, I'm told that $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,0,-1)$ are specific vector solutions for $Ax=b$. Also, the vector $(1,1,2)$ solves $Ax=0$. I need to find the general solution for $Ax=b$ and $Ax=0$. how do I approach such a question?

Comment: By linearity, if $A\pmatrix{1\\1\\2}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$, then $A\pmatrix{a\\a\\2a}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$

Comment: I suggest you try and find another vector $x$ such that $Ax=0$ that isn't a scalar multiple of $(1,1,2)^T$

Comment: @MatthewPilling How? no other information was given

Comment: If $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2=b$, then $A(x_1-x_2)=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, That's the way I tried to solve this question - but this way tells us that the general solution is (0,t,2t), and (1,1,2) isn't in this solution